# What's the American or British English equivalent to "take a download from", meaning get to know the information from someone?

Tags: american-english, british-english, phrase-requests, subcontinental-english

In Indian English, we often use the phrase "take a download from" which isn't common outside India or at least South Asia. This phrase means to get to know the information from someone.

For example, if I am not going to join a class as a student due to illness, I will say, "Mr. Abc will join the class and I will take a download from him." How would a British or American speaker express this sentence?

Comment: Please don't answer this in comments. Write an answer.

Comment: Are you looking for something informal/slangy (either specific to some industry or more general), or something you could use in your most polite and elevated writing? There are lots of slang terms for this, although it's not always certain how widely known they are.

Comment: @StuartF I would like to know the same both in formal and informal contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This phrase means to *get to know the information from someone*.

For a general verb:

**to  brief / be briefed**

**brief** (v.)

> To give essential information to
>
> *The president is being **briefed** by his advisor* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brief)

---

> The voice at the other end quickly **briefed** him on a missing file
> labeled in code which Johnson later identified as the Jeremy Eastman
> file. [Mel Walter; *Justice Perverted*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Justice_Perverted/zcUIEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=briefed%20him%20missed&pg=PT243&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> “I'll **brief** her and let her know what she missed.” [Jerri
> Williams; *Greedy Givers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Greedy_Givers/pi2lDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=brief%20him%20about%20the%20missed&pg=PT245&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

---

Perhaps more appropriate for missed lessons is:

**to fill someone in on**

> *US*
> *Informal*
>
> To provide someone with additional facts, details, etc. about
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fill-someone-in-on#:%7E:text=fill%20someone%20in%20on%20in,about)

**fill in** (v.)

> To give necessary or recently acquired information to
>
> *I'll fill you in* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fill%20in)

---

> Rachel, my very best friend, would come up to visit me daily and
> **fill me in on** all the things I had missed at school. [Jo Sudenly; *I Can't Relate*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/I_Can_t_Relate/hpKLRPrJiNUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=filled%20me%20in%20on%20what%20i%20missed%20at%20school&pg=PA25&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> “Wait for me at your locker so we can walk home together,” I said.
> “You need to **fill me in on** what I missed. [Yolanda Ridge; *Inside
> Hudson Pickle*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Inside_Hudson_Pickle/KyAzDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=filled%20me%20in%20on%20what%20i%20missed%20at%20school&pg=PT10&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to say, "I will get a brief from Mr. ABC."?

Answer (score 1):

"I shall have to miss tomorrow's lecture, but I've asked Mary to take notes for me" or "to give me a copy of her notes".